# How to add Apache Maven to PATH permanently

Tags: maven, unix

When I add Apache Maven to PATH using

```
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
```

and then check `echo $PATH`

I can see that bin was added to PATH. However if I repeat `echo $PATH` later, it disappears from PATH and `mvn --version` returns:

```
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:
 * maven
 * maven2
```

How to add maven to PATH permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH` in ~/.bashrc